Change key bindings in Apple Mail
Is there a way to change (actually, remove) key bindings in Apple Mail?
I sometimes find myself switching between tasks and impatiently backspacing over some word in an editor - only to find that I've sent a bunch of backspace events to Mail and apparently deleted the N newest messages from my inbox. (And worse, 'Undo' doesn't help me - it always undoes a bunch of things that I did earlier, but not the deletion of things that I'm now frantically trying to remember what they were.)
Ideally, of course, I'd like for these involuntary deletions to be undoable. But failing that, is there a way to change the association of keyboard events to actions in Apple Mail so that this specific error cannot happen? I'd gladly restrain myself to deleting messages only with the mouse.
